# Converting between shortest path problems

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, network-flow

> Given a weighted digraph $G$, and collections of vertices $R, S \subset
> V$ , consider the problem of finding a shortest length path joining
> a vertex $r\in R$ to a vertex $s\in S$. Reduce this to the shortest
> path problem from a given vertex to all other vertices.

I have been looking at this question for a while and I'm struggling to articulate what I am thinking. Clearly I should start by taking some fixed $a\in R$ and finding all the shortest paths from *a* to every other vertex, but I am unsure how to create the paths from any other $r\in R \setminus a$ to $s\in S$ since I cannot guarantee they are the shortest.

Comment: Do you need a [many-one reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(complexity)#Types_and_applications_of_reductions) or just a Turing reduction?

Comment: @Karl I think I am just supposed to reword the problem as I haven't encountered either reduction in this course.

Comment: Or maybe a [polynomial time reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction)? Can you make multiple calls to the shortest paths subroutine? I'd review your notes to make sure.

Comment: @Karl Polynomial Time is the only reduction we have covered but even then very briefly. Maybe that's why I'm struggling? The whole question is written above so I assume anything goes.

Comment: Yeah, "anything goes" isn't a well-defined task. If the problem says "reduce this", it should be clear what kind of reduction they're asking for. If it's a polynomial reduction, then (according to the Wikipedia definition) your solution can make multiple calls to the subroutine (e.g. one for every element of $R$).

Comment: @Karl I think I just overthought it then. Thanks!

Comment: It's conceivable you could transform the given graph into a new graph on which a single call to the subroutine solves the problem for the original graph, but I don't see how this would work. It's important to know for sure whether that's a requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce a dummy "supersource" node $r_0$ and a directed arc with weight $0$ from $r_0$ to each $r\in R$.  Now solve a shortest path problem from $r_0$ to all vertices.  Let $d(r_0,i)$ be the resulting shortest-path distances.  For the path that corresponds to $\min_{s\in S} d(r_0,s)$, the first arc indicates which $r\in R$ to use.

A similar idea with an additional dummy supersink node $s_0$ further reduces the problem to a single-source, single-sink shortest path problem.